Where should you store the custom configuration file in Apache Superset?
Installation method: Docker Compose.
Apache Superset creates a Python configuration file for itself at the following path relative to root:
/superset/config.py
I get that you're supposed to copy this and create your own file to store custom configurations.
Assuming you're working in Docker, does it matter what path you choose on your host system?
If I were to create a bind mount between, say:
/mysupersetconfig/ and /config in the volume would that work? Or do I specifically need to mount the file within the /app path in the Superset app container?
Attempted to create the config file at a path outside /app and Docker didn't like it ... wondering whether that's actually the source of the problem

The way I'm doing this is:

My docker-compose.yaml file sources a .env file, like the way this docker-compose.yaml file loads this .env file.  The .env file has the line PYTHONPATH=/app/pythonpath:/app/docker/pythonpath_dev.
Relative to the directory with the docker-compose.yaml file and where I run docker compose up, I have a file in a subdirectory docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py.

I think you could put your config file other places on your host system, as long as you could create the bind mount as you describe and add that to the python path.  But the above worked for me out of the box so I never changed it.  I'm using the same path that file lives when you clone the Superset repo, https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py.
In terms of how it interacts with config.py: config.py is a useful reference as it contains all the possible settings you could override.  Anything in your superset_config.py file will overwrite the config.py defaults so you only need to specify in your superset_config.py what you need to change from the default.  At a minimum this will be a good value of SECRET_KEY=.
Note: the Superset docs describe naming your file superset_config_docker.py when deploying with Docker Compose, as far as I know that mostly adds confusion but FYI in case you want to try that or see it mentioned in the docs.
